# How do perform polynomial features and linear regression on 3 dimensional data (x,y,z)?

Tags: python, linear-regression, polynomials

I need help performing polynomial features on 3 dimensional data and performing linear regression to create a line of best fit on the 3 dimensional polynomial.

I have a random dataframe with x, y, and z as the columns that forms a polynomial scatterplot.
X and Y are similar values while z is vastly different.
Example:

```
X=(-3,9,-20,-8,-14)
Y=(-2,8,-19,-8,-13)
Z=(-960,110,4867,-149,1493)
```

I have done this for 2 dimensional data but not 3d.

```
poly=PolynomialFeatures(degree=2,include_bias=False)
X_poly=poly.fit_transform(X.reshape(-1,1)) 
X_poly[0]
```

However, how do I handle the data when I have x, y, and z? Do I need to perform poly.fit_transform x and y?

Next I did linear regression

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

LinReg = LinearRegression()
LinReg.fit(X_poly,z)
```

Then when I create test data for x and y and perform the predict method on z, the resulting line is linear instead of a polynomial.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. I needed to pass a DataFrame containing only x and y through the polynomial features and then use the XY_poly and z in the linreg.fit(). This trains the model for my next steps to create the line of best fit for the polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

When `PolynomialFeatures` says that `fit_transform()` method requires `x` and `y`, here `x` is an n-dimensional array of features and `y` are the target values which are optional. In your case I would do the following:

```
X=(-3,9,-20,-8,-14)
Y=(-2,8,-19,-8,-13)
Z=(-960,110,4867,-149,1493)

foo = np.array([X, Y, Z])
foo = foo.transpose() # This transposes the array to bring it to shape (n, 3)
poly = PolynomialFeatures(3)
poly.fit_transform(foo)
```

One this is done you can use `fit_transform(foo)`.

Comment: Thank you for your input. What would I do when I do the linear regression portion? It requires 2 positional arguments which usually I do the x_poly and y, but with the array I no longer has 3 separate portions.

Comment: Ok, in that case you need to explain what is that you are trying to predict?